# "Ghost" ng-click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-digest

Just when I thought I knew Angular pretty decently, I run into this situation:

Can someone explain how this is possible?

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/u08jgd4g/1/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <button ng-click="WTF" ng-bind="labelText()"></button>

  <div ng-show="showMe()">
    Hello, World!
  </div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    var show = true;

    $scope.labelText = function() {
        return !show ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
    };

    $scope.showMe = function() {
        show = !show;
        return show;
    };

};
```

If you haven't caught the issue yet: the button has an `ng-click` function that doesn't exist, yet when you click on the button, the div toggles and the button value changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not because the function doesn't exist, it's because that click is triggering a `$digest` cycle. So the cycle runs and evaluates your `ngShow` and `ngBind` functions.

Those 2 functions simply flip a variable to the opposite of what it was and apply the result. So all that's happening is you trigger a digest cycle and trip your functions that are bound in the view.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have used `ng-click` function, which runs a digest cycle after evaluation of expression given on `ng-click` directive. Resultant all the `watcher` function gets evaluated which why your value is getting toggle on each click.

Behind the scene when you use `ng-show` directive with an expression, angular internally puts that expression inside the `watcher` array which there under `$scope` object. You can see the collection of `watcher`'s object inside the `$scope.$$watchers` object.